# Wifi and Lan on same subnet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip, home-networking

Currently I have a pfsense router/switch that is wired to a wifi hubspot (the router is not wifi enabled). Is there a way to set this up so that all network devices remain on the routers subnet of `192.168.1.1`. Currently the lan devices reside on `192.168.1.X`, while wlan has its own subnet of `192.168.X.X`. I am looking into bridging currently.

Comment: Yes one subnet is fine for all local clients, wired and wireless. No reason why your network cares what is a wireless and what is a wired client. Your pfsense router only cares so far is it keeps track of which clients are wired and wireless so it can display the connection summary. You have two processes that manage your network (3 with firewall), you have *dhcp* that hands out IP addresses and updates your *nameserver* so the rest of your subnet can resolve what box got what address. The wired or wireless is nothing more than how you connect.

Comment: Now you can only have one device providing *dhcp* and *name resolution* services. (they can be on different devices). You can't have dhcp running on both the pfsense and the hubspot (that would result in potentially the same address getting handed out to two devices) Whatever device dhcp runs on, it needs to be able to update the nameserver so name resolution happens correctly. Getting this set up is key - not whether the connection is wired or wireless.